# What is the name of the VSIX that shows type members on mouse hover?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

Used to have that extension under Visual Studio 2010 but I can't find it again.

The extension provide the following helper :

- When hovering mouse over a type in the code editor a small window would pop-up and show members inside the type, saving the hassle to open the file to see what members that type contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be talking about Solution Navigator feature of [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/).

> Solution Navigator also provides interactive tooltips in C# and VB code (replacing the default “quick info” tooltips) that give you the same kind of data, but right at your fingertips.

Comment: Yes it's that one, unfortunately the feature has been removed in the 2012 version.